# Renaming the JAR file when it is run

Tags: java, file, rename

I need to be able to rename the jar file when a person runs it.

For example, say the file was called "abc.jar", when you run it, it renames it.

I'm going to use UUID.randomUUID() for this and maybe extend to a list of strings in the future, but for now I just need to know how to rename it.

I have tried;

```
File f = new File(UUID.randomUUID());
jarFile.renameTo(f);
```

But I understand now that you can't use a File for a .jar.

Any idea?

Either this or extract it and rename it.

Comment: You can wrap it in a script that changes the name of the underlying jar when the script is invoked

Comment: @amphibient can I do this without having to run a different file? Can I do this when the jar file is ran?

Comment: you may be able to do it in the main method of the Jar but it may cause a deadlock

Comment: Hmm okay. Thank you dude.

Comment: You might be able to do a clever hack using Runtime.exec.  As the last line of your program call Runtime exec to execute (a) a several second sleep, (b) a rename of the jar.  This will run in a separate process which should allow the JVM to terminate thus releasing the lock on your jar file.  I have never done this, so no guarantees.

Comment: Just curious - what's the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @AndrewS it may sound strange but I'm coding a sort of "cheat" for a game, and to keep it mostly undetectable (so nobody can search the name of it) it will be renamed to a random UUID each time it is ran.

EJK how would I call a sleep? Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), where would I find a tut. for the parameters? Cheers.

Comment: You probably want to look at "obfuscation", as renaming a jarfile will stop almost no one.

Comment: @jdv that isn't what I'm getting at. I don't want people to be able to search up the cheat name on a persons computer. This is why it has to have randomly selected names.

Comment: I repeat: renaming a jarfile will stop only people who you don't need protecting from.

Comment: @jdv if the program was called "abc", then a person could use the Everything program to search up abc, but if the program is renamed to a UUID and also deleted, then the "Everything" program will not show any results.

Comment: If I know it's probably a Jarfile, I could find it in seconds. Easy to search for file types and inside Jarfile, which are just zip files.

Comment: @jdv not if the jar file is deleted.

Comment: This conversation no longer makes any sense. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, but I can assure you  that you are going about the wrong way. Your security is no security at all. You may as well be doing nothing at all.

Comment: @jdv don't worry, I can't explain the contest via text. But trust me, renaming it to a random name is necessary.